# Add a table to popup using js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popup

I'm just starting to study leaflet and I want to add a table to the marker as an experiment, I seem to do everything according to the rules, but the text that should be in the form of a table is output in plain text cell 1 cell2. I will be glad of any help. Thanks!

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [10.0, 5.0],
    minZoom: 2,
    zoom: 2,
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
}).addTo(map)

var popup = "<table><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>"
    var m = L.marker([51.30,0.07]).bindPopup(popup
    ).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Everything is ok, the popup generates a table with two columns of text.

Comment: Adding a border to the table, or using the browser's inspection tools, should reveal that it's a table indeed.